# Is there an efficient method to remove elements from a sorted vector in order?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

Consider a sorted list of numbers `A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` from where one element will be eliminated at each step.

Suppose, I remove `A[4]` item, we have `A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. 
Then I remove `A[4]` item again, we have `A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9}` 
Then `A[7]` item, we have `A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8}` 
Then `A[0]` item, we have `A = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8}` and so on.

Consider that we know the indices of the elements to be removed in each `kth` array beforehand i.e [4, 4, 7, 0...]. Further, it could be interesting to note how the indices for the `kth` array is calculated at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128352/755.

If I were to implement this in C++ and `A` was a `std::vector`, I would need to call `A.erase(A.begin()+k)` each time and we will have an algorithm that runs in `O(n^2)`. I cannot even use `std::remove` here as elements do not repeat.

What would be the most efficient approach here? 
Also, is it possible to finally print the sequence of numbers extracted in order?

Comment: Reverse the order of the indices to be removed add to them: 7+2, 4+1, 4+0, so you get 9, 5, 4. If you want the resulting sequence to be sorted, use  `vector::erase` on each index in that order. If the result doesn't need to be sorted, swap each index (9, 5, 4) with `vector::back()` and `resize(size()-1)`.

Comment: You can use remove_if function. It has approximately O(n) complexity. You can find the API from here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I'm not sure I understand your approach. You seem to be using vector::erase anyway and if I were to remove element 0 after 4, 4, 7, I'll end up removing A[0+3] instead of A[0].

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari, I cannot seem to understand how we can apply remove_if here?

Comment: maybe it can be useful to discover the real indexes of the removals, for example, (4,4,7,0) will remove, in fact, the indexes (4,5,8,0) of the original array. It can be done in O(n²) but in this case n will be at most the size of the original array.

Comment: Daniel, 4,4,7,0 will remove 4,5,9,0, right?

Comment: if you use std::vector its gonna be `O(n)` worst case per removal, if you code some tree data structures likes segment-tree, implict treap or something similar you can achieve `O(log n)` deletion time (access time will increase to `O(log n)` though), actually some C++ compiler (gnu c++ i think) has built in ordered tree data structure template which supports all std::set operations + finding `k-th` element in `O(log n)` time

Comment: @Ganesh Yes, if the vector needs to be sorted after the removal I use `vector::erase`, like in this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/vsfxfE). Feeding it an unordered list of indices to remove complicates things and the example is likely not very effective though. The general idea is to remove the elements at the end first since it makes the `erase` more effective.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, not sure if your approach ensures correctness of the index values computed. If we are to remove 4, 4, 7, 0 using your approach, we get the indices 7+3, 4+2, 4+1, 0+0 i.e. 10, 6, 5, 0. Index 10 isn't even valid.

Comment: @Ganesh No, did you look at the [example](https://godbolt.org/z/vsfxfE)? It compensates for the new info regarding feeding it an unordered list of indices to remove. It can be done smarter though instead of partitioning the indices like I did.

Comment: @Photon, at best we can reach `O(logn * logn)`?

Comment: @Ganesh for your problem `print sequence of removed numbers from arrray` the total complexity will be `O(n log n)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, your code looks great!

Comment: Ok check this example. If you need further help, I can add a specific solution for your question. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdremove-stdremove_if-c/

Comment: @Ganesh Thanks, but it's not that good :-) Removing {4,4,7,0,2,4} would make it remove them in this order {9,5,4,6,3,0} but {9,8,5,4,3,0} would be better.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, do you mean it would be better if it was {9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 0}. Not sure how the 8 got in there. If we were to associate the value k after (k-1) removals with the index value and use your algorithm, we could extract the sequence by placing each element at kth location in a new vector?

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari, I think `std::remove` does a full pass through the vector each time it is called? I'm still not sure how that would give us an efficient solution. Please share your specific solution.

Comment: Removing {9,8,5,4,3,0} gives the same result as removing {9,5,4,6,3,0} or {4,4,7,0,2,4}. It's only a matter of reordering and recalculating the indices. With a good reordering one can also see that the actual calls to `erase` could be reduced to 3 only: {8-9}, {3-5} and {0}

Comment: If it helps, I'm calculating the indices for the `kth` array using a specific condition - https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128352/755

Comment: @Ganesh Ok, well, yes "_Is it possible to figure out the index of element pk without removing..._" in your question there is indeed possible as I showed above. One could possibly apply some bubblesort-like algorithm on the indices to recalc them in decending order to be able to minimize the calls to `erase` and to have to move as little data as possible.

Comment: @Ganesh remove_if  removes from the range [first, last) so it's complexity is linear, on the other hand, remove delete the element which it is matched.

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari, what will be the predicate given to `std::remove_if`?

Comment: In your question, you said that you know the index of the element in vector to be deleted so you are looking for a efficient way to delete this item like we are doing in array type structures. So remove_if gives you an opportunity of using similar fast deleting system of an array object in the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

This might be Captain Obvious sort of answer, but if the constraint is on time complexity and not space, then the most obvious thing to do would be populate a second vector in the order of removal from the first vector. The elements to be removed from the original vector can be marked in some fashion while iterating the vector in the 1st pass. This would be a O(1) step. Once all k extractions are performed, erase + remove_if can be invoked on the vector, and this would be an O(n) step.

So, the overall complexity of the code should be O(n).

I've provided a sample code here for illustration. Please note that there are some loops in the code which are simply to setup the input data set, and a black box algorithm to determine which element to extract.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

void populate_vector(std::vector<int>& my_vec)
{
    std::default_random_engine gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 100);    //Arbitrarily restricting range to 100

    std::vector<bool> bitmap;
    std::unordered_map<int, bool> num_map;

    auto dice = std::bind(distribution, gen);
    auto capacity = my_vec.capacity();

    while (capacity-- > 0)
    {
        auto ran = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            ran = dice();
            if (num_map.find(ran) == num_map.end())
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        my_vec.emplace_back(ran);
        num_map.emplace(std::make_pair(ran, true));
    }
}

void print_vector(const std::vector<int>& my_vec)
{
    for (const auto& ele : my_vec)
    {
        std::cout << ele << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("#Elements and #Removal iterations are needed as args\n!");
    }

    auto count = std::stoi(argv[1]);    //Count of elements
    auto k = std::stoi(argv[2]);    //Number of iterations to remove elements
    std::vector<int> my_vec, k_vec;
    std::vector<bool> bitmap;
    my_vec.reserve(count);
    bitmap.reserve(count);

    std::fill(bitmap.begin(), bitmap.end(), false);

    //Setup problem data set
    populate_vector(my_vec);
    print_vector(my_vec);

    auto sentinel = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    //Simulating knowledge of kth index with a random selection
    std::default_random_engine gen;
    auto max_idx = my_vec.capacity() - 1;

    std::cout << max_idx << "\n";

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, max_idx);    //Arbitrarily restricting range to 100

    auto dice = std::bind(distribution, gen);
    auto idx = 0;

    while (k-- > 0)
    {
        //Irrelevant to the complexity of the actual problem
        //This loop is only for the kth element extraction
        while (true)
        {
            idx = dice();
            std::cout << "idx = "<< idx << "\n";
            std::cout << "bitmap[idx]" << bitmap[idx] << "\n";

            if (! bitmap[idx])
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        k_vec.emplace_back(my_vec[idx]);    // O(1)
        my_vec[idx] = sentinel; // O(1)
        bitmap[idx] = true; // O(1)
    }

    my_vec.erase(std::remove_if(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), [sentinel](const int& num){ return (num == sentinel); }), my_vec.end()); //O(n)

    print_vector(my_vec);
    print_vector(k_vec);

    return 0;
}
```